# Print result of query to jsp table Java Spring MVC jsp

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, date, model-view-controller

I need print to table person who older than 55 years but it print every person from DB. I don't know what is wrong.

Dao

```
@Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Book> old1() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
//        List<Book> bookListt = session.createQuery("SELECT BOOK_TITLE, BOOK_AUTHOR, birthday FROM bookmanager.books WHERE birthday <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 year)").list();
        List<Book> bookList1 = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT ID, BOOK_TITLE, BOOK_AUTHOR, born FROM bookmanager.book  WHERE born <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 year))").list();

        return bookList1;
    }
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "books", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String old(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("book", new Book());
        model.addAttribute("old", this.bookService.listBooks());

        return "books";
    }
```

and I try to print that person but it is wrong. Prints all peson from DB

How can I fix it?

```
<c:if test="${!empty old1}">
    <table class="tg">
        <tr>
            <th width="80">ID</th>
            <th width="120">Title</th>
            <th width="120">Author</th>
            <th width="120">Price</th>
            <th width="120">born</th>
            <th width="60">Edit</th>
            <th width="60">Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${old1}" var="book1">
            <tr>
                <td>${book1.id}</td>
                <td><a href="/bookdata/${book1.id}" target="_blank">${book.bookTitle}</a></td>
                <td>${book1.bookAuthor}</td>
                <td>${book1.price}</td>
                <td>${book1.born}</td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/edit/${book1.id}'/>">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/remove/${book1.id}'/>">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
```

Comment: `[DATE_ADD(CURDATE()]` <-- why are there square brackets here?  This isn't MySQL syntax AFAIK.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen IDEA nderline this part red color.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen and without square brackets effect is still same. More option?

Comment: Please add sample data to your question and then add the current output from the query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen query work correct

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen check my jsp. Mb there is wrong.

Comment: `${book.price/100}${book.price%100}` <-- what is this supposed to be doing?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen for print price in double. In model price int. Is that important? Problem is another.

Comment: I don't understand that formula.  What is wrong with the output from the JSP, and is the output for the price part of the problem?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen forget about "price". Let's print without price. Problem is that when I select person from DB they print all without query.

Comment: Again, please edit your question and show what the problem is.  Having a hard time following you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I need to select from DB person who older than X years and print to table that persons.

Comment: OK, we just went in a big circle, so I'm done for now.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen print every person but not selected. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether your Hibernate/Java code is completely correct, but your MySQL query looks off.  If you want to target all books whose `born` field is older than 55 years from the current date, then use this:

```
SELECT id, bookTitle, bookAuthor, birthday
FROM Book
WHERE born <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 55 year)
ORDER BY born;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change a query to criteria. Native sql query not worked.

```
public List<Book> listBooks() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();


        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(new Date());
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 55);

        List<Book> bookList = session.createCriteria(Book.class).add(Restrictions.le("born", calendar.getTime())).list();


        return bookList;
    }
```